# Tuple index out of range in Airflow XCom

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am working with Airflow and XComs and want to return multiple values from the function, however, I am facing the problem. The following is my code:

```
def authenticate_api():
    #Define the global variables
    # API authentication
    url = 'odoo'
    db = 'db'
    username = 'admin'
    password = 'user'
    logging.info("Variables assigned")

    common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

    return db, models, uid, password

def get_max_date_from_odoo(**context):
    # Variables
    list = []
    list2 = []
    db = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='authenticate_api')
    models = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='authenticate_api')
    uid = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='authenticate_api')
    password = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='authenticate_api')

    #Get the customer id and date to use in the query
    datesandids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
        'res.partner', 'search_read',
        [[['is_company', '=', False]]],
        {'fields': ['x_customer_register_date', 'x_customer_id']})
```

It returns:

```
('database', <ServerProxy for odoo069/xmlrpc/2/object>, 1, '1234')
```

as a tuple. Therefore I am getting an error of:

```
(db, uid, passwd ) = params[0], int(params[1]), params[2]\nIndexError: tuple index out of range\n'>
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: I see the indexError but you can't call `int(params[1])` Because `params[1] = <ServerProxy for odoo069/xmlrpc/2/object>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the individual values, you are returning the tuple containing all values and assigning it to all of the variables.

Try this:

```
def get_max_date_from_odoo(**context):
    # Variables
    list = []
    list2 = []
    db, models, uid, password = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='authenticate_api')
   ...
```

That should save you hitting the database 4 times to get the same value.

Alternatively, since we are unsure of the type that is returned from the XCOM (expected tuple, could be json encoded).

```
def get_max_date_from_odoo(**context):
    # Variables
    list = []
    list2 = []
    values = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='authenticate_api')
    if isinstance(values, tuple):
        db, models, uid, password = values
    elif isinstance(values, str):
        import json
        values = json.loads(values)
        db, models, uid, password = values
```